# DBT Error: unknown command "init" for "dbt"

Tags: visual-studio-code, dbt

Hello I am using VS Code (on Windows 10) and tried to initial a new DBT project.

I used Conda to setup virtual environment with python 3.9.18

```
python --version
Python 3.9.18
```

```
    dbt init
    WARNING: version 0.34.13 of the dbt Cloud CLI is now available. 
    During beta, old versions are not supported - upgrade now!

    Error: unknown command "init" for "dbt"
    Run 'dbt --help' for usage.
```

Then I used dbt --help, it shows a list of command, but there is no init

```
    dbt --help
    WARNING: version 0.34.13 of the dbt Cloud CLI is now available. During beta, old versions are not supported - upgrade now!

    The dbt Cloud CLI - an ELT tool for running SQL transformations and data models in dbt Cloud. For more documentation on these commands, visit: docs.getdbt.com

    Usage:
      dbt [command]

    Available Commands:
      build         Run all seeds, models, snapshots, and tests in DAG order
      cancel        Cancel the most recent invocation
      clean         Delete all folders in the clean-targets list (usually the dbt_packages and target directories.)
      clone         Create clones of selected nodes based on their location in the manifest provided to --state.
      compile       Generates executable SQL from source, model, test and analysis files.
      deps          Pull the most recent version of the dependencies listed in packages.yml
      docs          Generate or serve the documentation website for your project
      help          Help about any command
      list          List the resources in your project
      parse         Parses the project and provides information on performance
      reattach      Reattach to the most recent invocation to retrieve logs and artifacts
      retry         Retry the nodes that failed in the previous run.
      run           Compile SQL and execute against the current target database.
      run-operation Run the named macro with any supplied arguments.
      seed          Load data from csv files into your data warehouse.
      show          Generates executable SQL for a named resource or inline query, runs that
                    SQL, and returns a preview of the results. Does not materialize anything to
                    the warehouse
      sl            Query metrics or metadata against your semantic layer.
      snapshot      Execute snapshots defined in your project
      source        Manage your project's sources
      test          Runs tests on data in deployed models.
      version       Print version information

    Flags:
      -h, --help   help for dbt

    Use "dbt [command] --help" for more information about a command.
```

Can someone please help?  Thank you

Comment: are you sure you have the right version of dbt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears you have installled the dbt cloud cli by mistake,

Instead of `pip install dbt` you want `pip install dbt-[adapter name]`.

Because the dbt cloud CLI is meant to interact with an existing dbt cloud project, it seems init is not included.

Answer (score 0):

I'm running python 3.12.0 on Windows 11. I installed dbt-core, dbt-postgres and dbt-snowflake using pip, e.g.:
pip install dbt-core
pip install dbt-postgres
pip install dbt-snowflake

All of these ran successfully

I see the same exact problem as original poster. To clarify, when I run dbt --help, the list of commands does NOT include debug or init.

When I run dbt --version, it shows:
dbt Cloud CLI - 0.35.4 (92dfbed1bf88b754b03e0bc48eb971e4a35d7023 2024-01-10T20:37:05Z)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).